# MIME application/download

Tags: php, file-upload, mime

I am working on a PHP upload script which allows uploading only PDF files. I am checking for the `application/pdf` MIME type before uploading. I have a PDF from my client that I am testing the upload script with and it is failing the upload error check and telling me that the file is a MIME type of `application/download`. I did download the PDF from the client via GMail. I also tested this with a PDF that I created in Photoshop and the script tells me that it is also of `application/download` type.

Here is how I am checking:

```
$mimeType = 'application/pdf';

if($_FILES[$filesName]['type'] != $mimeType)
{
  throw new UploadErrorException('File is not of correct type.');
}
```

I am trying to get the Fileinfo extension installed on my server (per grunk's advice), but for now I am looking for something to work without it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The only reliable method to check MIMEtype is fileinfo  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php  How do you check this information ? A little extract of your code could be helpfull

Comment: @grunk - I just added a snippet of the code. I currently do not have fileinfo installed on my server. I am going to see if I can get it installed now. Thank-you

Comment: How I would like test this problem, how I can prepare pdf file with application/download mime type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your upload script allows any file type *as long as the client says it's PDF*. Some browsers can not determine MIME types (duh, since determining MIME types is a hard problem) and just send a generic one. The correct way to check for the "real" MIME type is to use [fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).

If you don't have fileinfo, use the following drop-in replacement (PDF only):

```
if (!class_exists('finfo')) {
  class finfo {
     function buffer($string) {
       switch (substr($string, 0, 4)) {
       case '%PDF': return 'application/pdf';
       default: return 'application/binary';
       }
     }
     function file($file_name, $options=0, $context=NULL) {
       $f = fopen($file_name, 'rb', false, $context);
       if ($f === false) return false;
       $magic = fread($f, 4);
       fclose($f);
       return $this->buffer($magic);
    }
  }
}
$finfo = new finfo();
echo $finfo->file('test.pdf');
```

Comment: @letseatfood I don't think there was anything akin to today's concept of file formats then. `file` predates the internet, dating back to 1973.

Comment: Oh, interesting... but I was just wondering how to check for mime-type without fileinfo (my server doesn't have it). I should have worded my comment differently.

Comment: @letseatfood Wrote a short hack and added it to the answer. Only recognizes PDF though.

Comment: On a Linux/Unix/Posix system the 'file' command will return a (good) guess as to the contents. For about the past 10 years, versions of the program will also return the mime type, e.g. $mime_type=`file -i sample.pdf`

Comment: Hi phihag. Thanks for writing out that script for me. Unfortunately it is not echoing anything for me. It seems that I really just need to get fileinfo installed as you have said. I think my time will be better spent getting fileinfo up and running. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @letseatfood It's returning false because the file could not be opened. Remove the @ before fopen to find out more. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use fileinfo for any reason you can open the uploaded file and check first byte in it.
As you want only pdf file it's pretty easy. Open a pdf file with a text editor and you probably can see something like

```
%PDF-1.5
```

So if the uploaded file contain %PDF , have a .pdf extension and application/pdf as  mime type, you have good chance to deal with the good type.

But as i already said , if you can use fileinfo it's a better solution

Comment: Thanks grunk. I am going to try and get fileinfo up and running.